performance of the NDEigensystem and DEigensystem
I can't find any result and I can't understand what is going wrong. Any help please? My code is:
Clear["Global`*"]
V[x_] := 10^2*(1 - Exp[-x])^2;
{L, B} = {-Laplacian[u[x], {x}] + V[x]*u[x],DirichletCondition[u[x] == 0, True]};
{vals, funs} = DEigensystem[{L, B}, u[x], {x, 0, Pi}, 5]
DEigenvalues[{L, B}, u[x], {x, 0, Pi}, 5]


Are you sure that an analytic solution exists? Anyway NDEigensystem and NDEigenvalues will work.

i use Wolfram Mathematica 12.0, the code is running without ending, is something wrong?

MMA 14.0 NDEigensystem and NDEigenvalues only take a fraction of a second. DEigensystem and DEigenvalues take so long that I abort.
